# Application requiring elevation

Tags: .net, debugging, permissions

I have a .NET executable that shows the (German) message when started:

> Eine Referenzauswertung wurde vom Server zurückgesendet

which I translate as

> A referral was sent back from the server

Googling about the message

- revealed some certificate problems, which I tend to exclude from my analysis, because the executable is not code-signed.
- says I shoud run the application as an administrator, which I don't know why, because the assembly manifest just says "asInvoker"

  ```
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="true" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
  ```

I then thought I would figure out something interesting in WinDbg, so I tried to run it under the debugger. However, it didn't even reach the initial breakpoint.

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.20153.1000 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

CommandLine: [...].exe
Cannot execute '[...].exe', Win32 error 0n740
    "Der angeforderte Vorgang erfordert erhöhte Rechte."
```

The German message translates as "The requested action required elevated privileges".

Digging much deeper using IL disassembly with dotPeek, I find that declaration on a method:

```
[PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
```

which obviously contradicts the manifest. But still, Windows was able to figure out that admin access is needed.

The whole analysis took about 3 hours. Is there an easier way to find out why a .NET application requests elevation?

Comment: have you tried uiAccess=false?

Comment: @magicandre1981: uiAccess alone did not help. Either it's still the "FullTrust" thing, or the Program Files folder or Code Signing. I have to set up Code Signing first. Didn't use it for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue with `WPRUI.exe` and it turns out, that applications that have `uiAccess="true"` set in manifest, have to be signed and have to be executed from inside "program files" or Windows folder.

So running it from any other location triggers that `"Der angeforderte Vorgang erfordert erhöhte Rechte."` message.

So, set change `uiAccess="true"` to `uiAccess="false"` to fix it.

Comment: It seems I totally overlooked uiAccess and didn't even consider it.

Comment: Try if setting it to false fixes it.

Comment: While probably helpful for this particular case, this answer doesn't address the part "Is there an easier way to find out why a .NET application requests elevation?"